# Is it possible to get Covid-19 and have 0 symptoms along the complete journey and hence cure by yourself without knowing?

Tags: covid-19, virus, infectious-diseases, symptoms, asymptomatic

In this [link](https://www.health.harvard.edu/diseases-and-conditions/covid-19-basics), in the section *How long is it between when a person is exposed to the virus and when they start showing symptoms?* mentions

> Recently published research found that on average, the time from exposure to symptom onset (known as the incubation period) is about five to six days. However, studies have shown that symptoms could appear as soon as three days after exposure to as long as 13 days later.

I have seen this other [link](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/coronavirus-incubation-period/) where we can see that the incubation could vary from 0 to 27 days.

Now [here](https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/11193056/how-to-treat-coronavirus/) mentions how long it last if you have got it, which says its 22 days.

[image]

If the Covid-19 goes after 22 days, then could be possible that one gets it and showing no symptoms at all, not even feeling bad at all, the whole time on the Covid-19 process?

If yes, is there a way to know that you already had it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although it doesn't makes much sense that the illness goes after day 22 if the incubation could last up to 27 days

Comment: This is just a typical timeline, individuals vary a lot. And it's jumbled because they've put both severe and non severe courses together. Someone at risk of death on day 18 isn't going to be suddenly free of illness 4 days later. Someone with limited symptoms might experience nothing but a cough.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to have no symptoms and be infected, various sources, e. g. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/32179137.

As for testing after 'clearing the infection', this would be what a serological scarring test would look for, e. g.:

- https://www.statnews.com/2020/03/27/serological-tests-reveal-immune-coronavirus/
- https://www.contagionlive.com/news/florian-krammer-phd-discusses-new-coronavirus-serological-assay.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: So Covid-19 infection could be like a ghost: one got it, felt _nothing_ during ~22 days, finally Covid-19 leaves the immune system, and end of the story? :)

Comment: Yes, that could be possible.

Answer (score 1):

From {1}:

> In COVID-19, The University of Padua, Veneto Region and the Red Cross tested the populationof Vò, Italy, 3300 people, to establish the natural history of the virus, the transmission dynamicsand categories of risk. "**they found >50 of those who tested positive to be asymptomatic**” according to Professor Sergio Romagnani.

FYI: [How can one predict whether an individual infected with the SARS-CoV-2 virus will be asymptomatic?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/21723/43)

---

References:

- {1}  2020-03-25 - Stanford COVID-19 Evidence Service - Addressing COVID-19 Face Mask Shortages [v1.2] https://archive.org/details/20200325stanfordcovid19evidenceserviceaddressingcovid19facemaskshortagesv1.2